# Variable doesn't exist :Date

Tags: apex, date

i write a small apex code snippet.

```
if(v.dataType == 'Date')
    {  System.debug('date is'+mapField.get(field1.name));
        System.debug('field is'+field1);
        String str = mapField.get(field1.name).fieldValue;
        Date x;
        if(str ==null)
        x= Date.newInstance(str.split('\\')[2],str.split('\\')[0],str.split('\\')[1]);

        if(Date.valueOf(dataType1) == x)
         conditionsResult.add(true);
         else conditionsResult.add(false);
    }
```

on line `x= Date.newInstance(str.split('\\')[2],str.split('\\')[0],str.split('\\')[1]);`
its giving me error

```
Variable does not exist: Date
```

but date is a global object i think.please help how to remove this error ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Date.newInstance` does not accept strings, it accepts integers according to the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_newInstance). You are passing in Strings.

You could possibly try the `Date.parse` method.